# Case statement in the where condition

Tags: sql-server

How to use the Case statement in the where condition  to check whether the Date is greater than other date if so the i Calculate a Date from my function and then check with Today's date and need to set the date in the where clause.

```
select L.FDGL as [FDGL],L.brn as [BRANCH Name], L.LoyaltyNo as [LoyaltyNo],
    L.Loan_no as [Loan No],L.Client_name as [Customer Name], convert(datetime,L.Loan_Dt,103) as [Loan Disburse Date],
    convert(datetime,L.Loan_DueDt,103) as [Due Date], convert(datetime,DATEADD(day, MFL_BL.[dbo].get_NPADAYS(U.[State]),(L.Loan_lsint+1)),103) as [NPA DATE]
from Loans L
    inner join users U on U.FDGL=L.FDGL
where Loan_stat='A'
    and (case when (L.Loan_lsint > L.Loan_DueDt) then getdate() else 0 end ) end )
```

Comment: Include your query. What you done so far to solve the issue

Comment: it is not good practice to call function inside Where condition.

Comment: select L.FDGL as [FDGL],L.brn as [BRANCH Name], L.LoyaltyNo as [Loyalty No],L.Loan_no as [Loan No],L.Client_name as [Customer Name], convert(datetime,L.Loan_Dt,103) as [Loan Disburse Date], convert(datetime,L.Loan_DueDt,103) as [Due Date], 
convert(datetime,DATEADD(day, MFL_BL.[dbo].get_NPADAYS(U.[State]),(L.Loan_lsint+1)),103) as [NPA DATE]from Loans L inner join users U on  U.FDGL=L.FDGL 
where Loan_stat='A' and (case when (L.Loan_lsint > L.Loan_DueDt) then getdate() else 0
end )
end )

Comment: (case when (L.Loan_lsint > L.Loan_DueDt) then getdate() else 0 end ) end )   -  this should be compared with some value(date)

Comment: Post your query in the question itself.

Comment: What's the point of putting a `CASE WHEN` in the *WHERE* statement?? You don't compare the result with anything

Comment: where Loan_stat='A' and case when (L.Loan_lsint > L.Loan_DueDt) then DATEADD(day,MFL_BL.[dbo].get_NPADAYS(U.[state]),L.Loan_DueDt) <=getdate() end

Comment: Why `convert(datetime,L.Loan_DueDt,103)`? Isn't `Loan_DueDt` a date or datetime already? If it's a string you have a serious bug. Depending on the format of the strings you may or may not be able to compare values at all

Comment: I suggest you write a proper, working SQL query *first*, then look into how or if it should be converted to LINQ

Comment: Why are  you using `CASE` in `WHERE` instead of `OR`? Describe what you want to do, not how you think the solution would look like

Comment: i need to check if the Date is greater than Due date if so i calaculate a date from a function and check with Today's date or else i put my Date in the else case

Comment: **1.** You are NOT COMPARING the `case expression` against anything. After the `and` there should be `column =` then the `case expression`. **2.** the `case expression` isn't valid or complete. You are trying to compare a function to `getdate()` after `then` **which you cannot do** `then` should just return a value, not compare 2 values. **3.** pretty sure those converts in the `select clause` should be `convert(varchar(10),...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual full query seems buried in a comment this is what appers to be that full query:

### Before:

```
SELECT
      l.FDGL AS [fdgl]
    , l.brn AS [branch name]
    , l.LoyaltyNo AS [loyalty no]
    , l.Loan_no AS [loan no]
    , l.Client_name AS [customer name]
    , CONVERT(datetime, l.Loan_Dt, 103) AS [loan disburse date]
    , CONVERT(datetime, l.Loan_DueDt, 103) AS [due date]
    , CONVERT(datetime, DATEADD(DAY, MFL_BL.[dbo].get_NPADAYS(u.[State]), (l.Loan_lsint + 1)), 103) AS [npa date]
FROM Loans l
INNER JOIN users u ON u.FDGL = l.FDGL
where Loan_stat='A' 
and case when (L.Loan_lsint > L.Loan_DueDt) 
         then DATEADD(day,MFL_BL.[dbo].get_NPADAYS(U.[state]),L.Loan_DueDt‌​) <=getdate() 
    end
```

1. You are NOT COMPARING the `case expression` against anything. After the `and` there should be some "column =" or similar, then the case expression.
2. The `case expression` as it stands right now isn't valid or complete. You are trying to *compare a function to getdate()* after `then` which you **cannot do**: 'then` should just return a value, not compare 2 values.
3. It is more conventional to convert to varchar in the select clause e.g. `convert(varchar(10),...,103)` for presentation in DD/MM/YYYY

### After

```
SELECT
      l.FDGL AS [fdgl]
    , l.brn AS [branch name]
    , l.LoyaltyNo AS [loyalty no]
    , l.Loan_no AS [loan no]
    , l.Client_name AS [customer name]
    , CONVERT(varchar(10), l.Loan_Dt, 103) AS [loan disburse date]
    , CONVERT(varchar(10), l.Loan_DueDt, 103) AS [due date]
    , CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(DAY, MFL_BL.[dbo].get_NPADAYS(u.[State]), (l.Loan_lsint + 1)), 103) AS [npa date]
FROM Loans l
INNER JOIN users u ON u.FDGL = l.FDGL
WHERE Loan_stat = 'A'
AND (
     l.Loan_lsint > l.Loan_DueDt
   OR 
     DATEADD(DAY, MFL_BL.[dbo].get_NPADAYS(u.[state]), l.Loan_DueDt) <= GETDATE()
    )
```

Boolean logic can replace the `case expression`. The logic shown above is a best guess as to your actual intention, but at least the syntax is valid.

It remains poor practice to rely on function calls in the where clause as it causes poor performance.

### ----

> if l.Loan_lsint >l.Loan_Duedt then in where clause i use l.Loan_Duedt
>   or else l.Loan_Lsint date

```
WHERE  Loan_stat = 'A'
AND (
          (
           l.Loan_lsint > l.Loan_DueDt
          AND
           DATEADD(DAY, MFL_BL.[dbo].get_NPADAYS(u.[state]), l.Loan_DueDt) <= GETDATE()
          )
    OR
          (
           l.Loan_lsint <= l.Loan_DueDt
          AND
           DATEADD(DAY, MFL_BL.[dbo].get_NPADAYS(u.[state]), l.Loan_Lsint) <= GETDATE()
          )
    )
```

Comment: I cannnot implement this since i need to get only one date based on the  condition if l.Loan_lsint >l.Loan_Duedt  then in where clause i use l.Loan_Duedt or else l.Loan_Lsint date.

Comment: l.Loan_Duedt OR  l.Loan_Lsint ..... **compared to WHAT?** Do you want to "use it" (one of those dates) in the function? but what do yo compare the function to? is the function compared to getdate()?

Comment: I have added a new where clause for consideration

Comment: That's really great! Now please choose the answer that best helped. **CLICK the TICK**.... this is so helpful as we then know the answer has been provided, and we can stop visiting questions over and over and over again

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like this

```
    CREATE TABLE #tmp (id int, date1 DATETIME, date2 DATETIME, date3 DATETIME)

    insert into #tmp values(1,'2017-01-01','2017-02-02',null)
    insert into #tmp values(2,'2017-05-01','2017-04-02','2017-11-09')

    SELECT * FROM #tmp
    WHERE date3 = CASE WHEN date1> date2
            THEN CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
         END

    DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Comment: What is the logic of this statement? Why `CASE WHEN` instead of `OR`? And what happens when `date1 <= date2`?

Answer (score -1):

```
where Loan_stat='A' and [your column name]=(

case 
    when (L.Loan_lsint > L.Loan_DueDt) then getdate() else [Date] end ) 
end )
```

`CASE` statement will return a value it will match with `[your column name]`.
In case statement first part return Date `Data` but second part return `int` type.
I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: A simple `AND ( ... OR ...)` would be a lot easier to use. Besides, what's the point of comparing a *date* with *0* ? There's no date 0

Comment: which column do you want to filter case statement